# Bardcode to contain transaction sum information

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, receipt

Is it possible to make the POS include the transaction amount in the barcode?
I need to create (i'm a developer) a system where the merchant can print giftcards on the receipt itself and then, when the buyer scans the barcode to his proprietory mobile app, his account will be credited with the amount on receipt.

Do you know if its "doable" using standard cash register operations / plugins?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're looking for a price embedded barcode which is possible. If I remember correctly embedded barcodes tend to begin with "2" or "02", a search can bring up more information on them I'm sure.

However this isn't a good idea, as if someone works out that this is the method in which you're crediting accounts, it wouldn't be difficult to spoof a barcode and give yourself some free money.

Comment: Agree about the spoofing. Do you have any ideas how to do the whole account crediting process then?

Comment: The gift card should contain a unique identifier which is stored in a database along with the value of the card--and perhaps ownership information. When the customer wishes to redeem their gift card, the bar code is scanned and the remaining value is looked up in the database and applied to the transaction.